# Argparse - configparser.Interpolation missing option error

Tags: python, configparser

I am using Argparse for fetching the necessary value from config file.

For example:

```
python arg.py --event_conf=/opt/open-stack-tools/track_events.conf --openstack_conf=/etc/nova/nova.conf
```

I need to fetch value from two different files.

I can be able to get the results as needed for one local config file.

But In case of fetching the necessary values from nova.conf file, it results in following error:

```
       Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "arg.py", line 36, in <module>
            oslo_messaging_rabbit= dict(config.items("oslo_messaging_rabbit"))
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 655, in items
            for option in options]
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 691, in _interpolate
            self._interpolate_some(option, L, rawval, section, vars, 1)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 723, in _interpolate_some
            option, section, rest, var)
ConfigParser.InterpolationMissingOptionError: Bad value substitution:
        section: [oslo_messaging_rabbit]
        option : logging_exception_prefix
        key    : color
        rawval : %(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d TRACE %(name)s %(instance)s
```

Is there any way to fix the same.

I have copied the necessary contents and created a new local file, I can see that it is working fine.

When I am using the nova.conf file it results in error.

I can't change the file which I am using.

So I need a fix for the particular error.

**Note:**

Adding more details as needed:

```
parser.add_argument("-c", "--event_conf",
                    help="Specify config file 1", metavar="FILE")
args1, remaining_argv1 = parser.parse_known_args()


parser.add_argument("-o", "--openstack_conf",
                    help="Specify config file 2", metavar="FILE")
args2, remaining_argv2 = parser.parse_known_args()


if args1.event_conf:
    config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
    print config.read([args1.event_conf])
    config.read([args1.event_conf])
    configdetails_section1 = dict(config.items("configdetails_section1"))
```

Comment: you need to post how you define config_file and config_file2 with argparse.

Comment: Also, your traceback is missing a line. What comes after `Bad value substituion:`? The precise value that's failing might be an important clue that helps track down the error.

Comment: i have edited the question with necessary details

Comment: Note that this is not a behavior for Argparse, as the title of the question defines. This is a behavior or ConfigParser (https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html). So it is better to change the title of the question to improve the knowledge base.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution for the same.

Actually issue was with the configparser which I have used.

Instead of **SafeConfigParser** I changed it to **RawConfigParser**.

Then I can be able to see that it is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Interpolation allows you to refer to values of the configuration while defining others. For example, in this config file:

```
[bug_tracker]
protocol = http
server = localhost
port = 8080
url = %(protocol)s://%(server)s:%(port)s/bugs/
username = dhellmann
password = SECRET
```

if you read like this:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('interpolation.ini')

print 'value =', parser.get('bug_tracker', 'url')
```

you will get:

```
value = http://localhost:8080/bugs/
```

that can be very useful, the problem seems that that you pass some values in run time. I mean you need the format string to actually substitute the values by yourself.

You can use `RawConfigParser` instead of `SafeConfigParser` but then you loose all the interpolations.

Instead you can suppress the interpolation for one specific value:

```
print 'value =', parser.get('bug_tracker', 'url', raw=True)
```

and the result would be:

```
value = %(protocol)s://%(server)s:%(port)s/bugs/
```

There is also the possibility that you need to combine interpolated values with some of them given in evaluation time. For example if you want to give the `user` in evaluation time, you can also include it into the config expression:

```
[bug_tracker]
protocol = http
server = localhost
port = 8080
url = %(protocol)s://%(user)s@%(server)s:%(port)s/bugs/
username = dhellmann
password = SECRET
```

and then you need to make something like this:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('interpolation.ini')

parser.set('bug_tracker', 'user', 'admin')
print 'value =', parser.get('bug_tracker', 'url')
```

and you'll get:

```
value = http://admin@localhost:8080/bugs/
```

Sorry that I didn't use your example. I did take the one in the documentation of another project. See the section: [Combining Values with Interpolation](https://pymotw.com/2/ConfigParser/#combining-values-with-interpolation)